# Haskell IO Sum up all inputs

Tags: haskell, io

I'm trying to sum up all the user inputs given via IO.
The sum should start with a value 0 and then add continuously the user inputs. The IO programm (main) should run until stopped and always take an input and add it to the previous sum.

```
print "Welcome!"
print "Current sum is = 0"
main = do putStrLn "Current sum = "++ read summy
      input <- getLine
      let summy = (read summy + read input)
      main
```

That's the code I tried to get it working. My problem is I am not able to define the sum at the beginning as 0 and I am not sure how I should solve the problem.

How can I do that?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

the problem you are having is that the function you define (`main`) is of type `IO ()` if you want to have a recursive sum you would need to pass on the current value.

```
mainSum :: Double -> IO ()
mainSum accumulator = do putStrLn $ "the current sum = " ++ show accumulator
                         input <- getLine
                         let summy = read input + accumulator
                         mainSum summy
```

But if you can avoid the `IO` part (in this case reading the input) I would recommend to separate it from the computational part. Also the function `read` is partial, i.e. `read "PWND!" :: Double` yields an error - which is not desireable - so switching to something like a

```
 safeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
```

might be a good idea to switch to in a future version of this program.

btw - your program as of now would not even compile - those `print`-statements are not correct haskell code if not included in a "bigger function" so try to do it like this

```
main :: IO ()
main = do print ...
          print ...
          mainSum 0
```